# How can I get if a column of a Pyspark dataframe contains NaN values?

Tags: python, pyspark

Is there an effective way to check if a column of a Pyspark dataframe contains NaN values? Right now I'm counting the number of rows that contain NaN values and checking if this value is bigger than 0. However, I wonder if this is actually a good way of doing so (ideally, the program should stop the check when it finds the first NaN).

This is what I'm doing (I'm trying to check if the column "col_w_nan" contains any NaN values):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import count, when, isnan

number_of_nans = df.select(count(when(isnan(df.col_w_nan), "col_w_nan")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just do a `.where` clause? It won't stop once it finds something, but it looks cleaner at least?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
number_of_nans = df.where(F.isnan('col_w_nan')).count()
```

Alternatively use `F.isnull` instead of `F.isnan` if you want null values.